# Как получить аватар миниатюрного вида из профиля vk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, вконтакте

Какой метод использовать для получения такого (см. прикрепленный скрин) миниатюрного вида аватарки профиля, которое используется при показе сообщений(круглая фотка-миниатюра) только большего размера?

[image: Отображение при показе сообщений]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://vk.com/dev/users.get

в котором в поле `fields` можно указать `photo_50`, которая является url квадратной фотографии пользователя, имеющей ширину 50 пикселей. В случае отсутствия у пользователя фотографии возвращается http://vk.com/images/camera_c.gif.

[все поля](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user?f=1.%2B%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%2B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: а метод crop_photo? https://vk.com/dev/objects/user?f=1.%2B%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%2B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F
нужна аватарка пользователя который авторизовался на сайте через вк

Comment: @werty ну хочешь, бери crop_photo. это не метод, это поле